# Proving equivalence between two asymptotic definitions

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> Define: Let $f,g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R^+$, $g(n)=\hat O f(n)$ if $\exists c>0: \forall n\ge 1 : g(n)\le cf(n)$.
>
> Prove that $\hat O$ and the definition of big $O$ are equivalent, i.e: $g(n)=\hat O f(n) \iff g(n)= O f(n)$

One side is simple, just take $n_0=1$, but how do I show that $g(n)=\hat O f(n) \Leftarrow g(n)= O f(n)$?

Suppose $\exists n_0,c>0: \forall n \ge n_0 :g(n)\le c f(n)$, we can't know what happens between $1$ and $n_0$. I thought about moving the functions by defining $x=n-n_0$ and then plugging $x$ to the functions, now we will have the requirements of $\hat O$ but it feels like cheating.

PS: I'm not sure what tags this should have.

Comment: The implication does not hold: try $f(1)=0$, $f(n)=1$ for every $n\ge2$, $g(n)=1$ for every $n\ge1$.

Comment: @Did I don't understand.

Comment: OK. What don't you understand?

Comment: Which implication doesn't hold?

Comment: The one you say you do not know how to show, which presumably is the subject of the question (amazing, eh?).

Comment: Wouldn't taking $c=1, n_0=1$ with your example work with both $O, \hat O$? @Did

Comment: The definition of $\hat O$ involves no $n_0$. Please show how (you think) the example in my comment would fit the definition of $g(n)=\hat O(f(n))$ (since surely you did check this before stating you were unable to understand this example, yes?).

Comment: Pretending? from your example we can agree that: $g(n)=O f(n)$, and there's also $c=1$ such that $\forall n\ge 1$ so we have $g(n)≤cf(n)$, which is $g(n)=\hat O f(n)$ @did

Comment: Huh? Sure that $g(1)\leqslant cf(1)$ with $c=1$?

Comment: I see now, I probably missed that before. It's not nice to say that my inability to understand is pretending, just a few more words to make it clear would've saved all of this. @Did

Comment: Since you see fit to mention this point *twice* (and I would much prefer to see you spend your energy on reading carefully the comments **written to help you understand and solve your question**, but...), where do you see "pretending" in my comments?

Comment: You edited it but I still saw it. BTW, the functions are positive, denoted by the $\mathbb R^+$ so it can't be $f(1)=0$ so the implication holds after all. @Did

Comment: By the way, if you intend $\mathbb R^+$ to denote $(0,+÷infty)$ instead of $[0,+\infty)$ (a convention which is by no means universal), don't you think your question could contain a mention of the fact? You know, just so that people do not lose their time **trying to help you**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the constant that works for $n_0$ and you know that below $n_0$ you just have two values $g(n)$ and $f(n)$ so you can use their quotient to give $c_n$. So you have $c_i$ for $1...n_0$ and the c from the big O definition. Cook up a new c from that finite set.

Comment: Are you saying to define a constant for each $n\in[1,n_0]$ such that $g(n)≤c_i f(n)$?

Comment: Yes. Because of that $n_0$ you have a finite amount of work to do ad-hoc.